# serial correlation problem in markov switching model

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the MSwM r package to estimate a nonlinear version of Bohn's (2008) FRF function based on the paper of ,Aldam et Créel (2018),   which can be represented as follows: $y_t = a_0 + \sum a_i x_{it} + \epsilon_t$.

Based on this specification, the residual term is correlated, and it should be modeled as an MA(1) process instead of the initial form. thus the model may be writen as: $y_t = a_0 + \sum a_i x_{it} + \epsilon_t + \rho \epsilon_{t-1}$

So does anyone have any idea how to overcome this problem?
Thanks.

I have encountered this complex challenge that involves modifying the msmFit function via a cochrane orcutt procedure. Despite my best efforts, I have been unable to find a solution or understand the underlying issue.